# Return type based on generic model in parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```js
function getModelDetails<T>(model: Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>): Record<keyof typeof model, unknown> {
  return (model as unknown) as Record<keyof typeof model, unknown>;
}
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

// person is assigned with an object with all the Person properties instead of only "firstName" and "lastName"
const person = getModelDetails<Person>({ firstName: 'jon', lastName: 'smith' });
```

Is there anyway to have the return type of whatever was passed into the generic function, instead of just returning all the Type's properties?

I also don't want to specify what properties I want to return, I basically wanna find a way to have a return type based on what properties were passed to the function.

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but thanks in advance ;)

**Desired**

```js
// person only with {firstName:"...", lastName: "..."}
const person = getModelDetails<Person>({ firstName: 'jon', lastName: 'smith' });
```

Comment: Do you mean `function getModelDetails<T, U extends Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>>(model: U): U`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately not quite, I wanna specify the Model, but not the model properties I'm passing as type, something like this `getModelDetails<Person>({firstName:"jon"})`, which would resolve in a returning type of only `{firstName:"..."}`.

Comment: That's what I tried to solve in my comment. The type of `U` should be `{ firstname: string }` and `U` is the return type. Have you tried my snippet?

Comment: Thanks again. But that way I would have to pass in both types, or am I missing something?
Like `getModelDetails<Person, {firstName: string}>({firstName:"jon"})`
And I don't want to have to pass this second type `U` to figure out the return type ;)

Comment: You have type deduction in TypeScript. The type of `U` can be deduced. You don't have to pass it. The function call wouldn't change.

Comment: Maybe I'm too ignorant on this matter, to understand what you are saying. But how would you call the function then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229946/discussion-between-pedro-figueiredo-and-jabaa).

Comment: when you deliberately cast a structural type to an explicitly named type - you lose all the information about the structural type and instead convert it to the named type. Once you treat the type `{ firstName: string; lastName: string }` as `{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string;  age?: number }` - you lose the exact and original type information of the object. Without said type information, typescript cannot know which properties are actually there. You have essentially generalized a specific type and explicitly told typescript to forget all the nitty bitty details.

Comment: Hum... Thanks a lot @Chase, you mean that with the current state of TS, it is not possible to do this type of inferrence right?

Comment: @PedroFigueiredo this is hardly a problem with TS. It's more of a logical fallacy - you cannot recover lost information, especially when you explicitly wanted to lose it. Your only choice is to somehow capture and save that type information instead of completely getting rid of it. A closure pattern - may or may not work. But since you're currently asking for both type inference (for the specific type info) and also type casting (explicit and manual) - both at the same time, conflicting each other - it's not exactly possible.

Comment: Note that, @LindaPaiste's answer already showcases the closure pattern. You may tweak it to your liking - but it is a great example for the whole "capture the type information before getting rid of it" pattern

Answer (score 2):

There are two generic values involved here: the type of the model and the subset of properties that we are passing.  You have said that you want to specify the first generic, but allow the second to be inferred.  This is not something that you can do with a single function.  You would need to use currying, aka a "double function".

```
function getModelDetails<Model>() {
    return function <Keys extends keyof Model>(model: Pick<Model, Keys>): Pick<Model, Keys> {
        return model;
    }
}
```

You could use the return type `[K in Keys]: Model[K]` instead of `Pick<Model, Keys>`.  They mean the same thing but if you write it out manually is then when you hover over the variable you get `{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }` instead of `Pick<Person, "firstName" | "lastName">`.  It's up to you which you prefer.

To use this function you need an extra set of parentheses `()` to invoke the first function which sets the `Model` to `Person`.

```
// person has type: Pick<Person, "firstName" | "lastName">
const person = getModelDetails<Person>()({ firstName: 'jon', lastName: 'smith' });

// error if adding unsupported property
// TS2345: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'somethingElse' does not exist in type 'Pick<Person, keyof Person>'
const person2 = getModelDetails<Person>()({firstName: 'jon', lastName: 'smith', somethingElse: '' });

// if you don't set the first generic then you get type Pick<unknown, never> because we don't have any default value
const person3 = getModelDetails()({ firstName: 'jon', lastName: 'smith' });
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w26aVw)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Can't give you the "Correct Answer" as this isn't exactly what I was looking for (not even sure if it is possible...).
As this isn't too good of a Developer Experience for the consumer of function. Anyway, there is no such thing as Perfect Software, so again, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: I'm biased to go with this second approach to be honest, seems like a better DX [Typescript Playground Link](https://cutt.ly/TzVQYmE)